# Can the TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS flag for CreateToolhelp32Snapshot be used on desktop Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-mobile

I'm having trouble with a call to CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() from a C++ Windows program, but it only happens in the field -- so far I'm unable to replicate it in the office. I noticed some references to the (undocumented) flag TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS online, which I think might help, but the pages turned up in a Google search are all about Windows Mobile applications. Does this flag work in desktop applications? (It's supposed to reduce the memory required by the snapshot.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS` is documented in the [CE part of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885189.aspx) but not the [win32 part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489%28VS.85%29.aspx) so I'm assuming it is CE only

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this flag is [documented for Windows CE 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885189.aspx), but it's not actually in the headers for Windows CE 5.0. Attempting to compile with it throws an undeclared identifier error.